# "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.android.projectrc.Listing" when using Firebase RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm attempting to load a specific set of data from Firebase (a user searches for a city and we get the nearest locations to it and store it in an array) and I'm having an issue populating a recyclerview with my results.  I get this error: `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.android.projectrc.Listing` - which seems to indicate that I'm getting Strings instead of a "Listing" - which makes sense considering the database is structured like so:

```
Listings
    {
      "-L01KIjNtpgq2H0VopCn" : {
        "LevelOfQuestionnaireCompletion" : true,
        "ListingData" : {
          "AircraftHouseRules" : {
            "Pricing" : "100",
            "SuitableForPets" : "Yes",
            "SuitableForSmoking" : "No",
            "SuitableForchildren" : "Yes"
          },
          "BasicInfo" : {
            "AirportCode" : "ATL",
            "City" : "Atlanta",
            "Country" : "United States",
            "ModelPlane" : "Learjet",
            "NameOfListing" : "Roomy 4- Seater",
            "NumberOfGuests" : "0",
            "Owner" : "WdWB80uRtUPRF2sOFH5uJr2Tfu12",
            "PrimarilySetupForGuests" : "Yes",
            "State" : "Georgia",
            "Street" : "6000 N Terminal PKWY",
            "ZipCode" : "30320"
          },
          "DetailedInformation" : {
            "IdealGuests" : "Big groups",
            "ImageRef" : {
              "-L01KUEWb8trSidSTzgW" : "5051E390-7FD5-4CEF-9C1B-EB959C13A4C2",
              "-L01KUEWb8trSidSTzgX" : "E2BCA170-0F7B-43B1-BAC6-BEBBB6DEF630"
            },
            "SummaryOfPlane" : "Give us a brief description of your plane..."
          }
        }
      },
      "-L035Y5c_i88HW-BOlbQ" : {
        "LevelOfQuestionnaireCompletion" : true,
        "ListingData" : {
          "AircraftHouseRules" : {
            "Pricing" : "1000",
            "SuitableForPets" : "Yes",
            "SuitableForSmoking" : "No",
            "SuitableForchildren" : "Yes"
          },
          "BasicInfo" : {
            "AirportCode" : "ATL",
            "City" : "Mableton",
            "Country" : "United States",
            "ModelPlane" : "Learjet",
            "NameOfListing" : "Roomy 7 Seater Plane",
            "NumberOfGuests" : "0",
            "Owner" : "DjElZ1UT7jOOS23kjGwIr6lP5u22",
            "PrimarilySetupForGuests" : "Yes",
            "State" : "Georgia",
            "Street" : "1368 Foxhall Place",
            "ZipCode" : "30126"
          },
          "DetailedInformation" : {
            "IdealGuests" : "Big groups",
            "ImageRef" : {
              "-L035nMB96ykxHolPYSE" : "B3488600-EFB8-4A7B-B60B-B595E4AFB52E"
            },
            "SummaryOfPlane" : "Give us a brief description of your plane..."
          }
        }
      },
      "-L0CiG0yGBvC0bHRjz3W" : {
        "LevelOfQuestionnaireCompletion" : false,
        "ListingData" : true
      }
    }
```

I'm only interested in the information under "BasicInfo" and have made a class to get the information relevant to the user:

**Listing.kt**

```
data class Listing(
        val ModelPlane: String = "",
        val AirportCode: String = "",
        val City: String = "",
        val State: String = "")
```

The relevant code is as follows:

**ListingAdapter.kt**

```
class ListingAdapter(listingModel: Class<Listing>, modelLayout: Int, viewHolderClass: Class<ListingHolder>, dbRef: DatabaseReference) :
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Listing, ListingHolder>(listingModel, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, dbRef) {
    override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: ListingHolder?, model: Listing?, position: Int) {
        viewHolder!!.planeModel.text = model!!.ModelPlane
        viewHolder.airportCode.text = model.ModelPlane
    }

}
```

**ListingHolder.kt**

```
class ListingHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    var planeModel: TextView = v.listing_plane_model
    var airportCode: TextView = v.listing_airport_code
}
```

And the code that glues it all together:

```
for (listing in keyList) {
    val listingReference = mDatabaseReference
            .getReference("Listings/$listing/ListingData/BasicInfo")
    listingReference.keepSynced(true)
    search_results.adapter = ListingAdapter(Listing::class.java, listings_view_layout, ListingHolder::class.java, listingReference)
}
```

I'm pretty sure there's something I missed (or messed up) in creating my Adapter class, but I'm not entirely sure what, as all the guides I've looked at seem to follow the same pattern I've done. (`$listing` corresponds to the unique ID given to every listing in the database e.g. `"-L0CiG0yGBvC0bHRjz3W"`)

Comment: what is dbref equal to?

Comment: Your whole model is wrong, no? Your `Listing` roughly looks like a `BasicInfo` in the database. And you are missing some fields

Comment: @PeterHaddad dbref is equal to listingReference

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not sure I follow - my Listing class doesn't have all the same data as BasicInfo because it's not relevant to the user. What about the model itself is wrong?

Comment: Maybe not wrong, but at least confusing. Your database holds a list of `Listings`. Your data class is named `Listing`, but the data you extract is within this `BasicInfo` block

Comment: Look at all the Firebase objects... Is there something in there that is `"BasicInfo" : "..."` instead of `"BasicInfo" : { ... }`?

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at - so I should move one level up and just pull out the data within BasicInfo manually? @cricket_007

Comment: Not necessarily. The error indicates somewhere in your data `BasicInfo` is a string, not an object.

Comment: @cricket_007 well yes, all the data within BasicInfo are strings, I guess my concern is how would I pull those strings out if I can't use the Listing class?

Comment: No, the **value** of `BasicInfo` itself... Not the data **within** the `{}` of your JSON dump

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean - it's saying that `BasicInfo` *itself* is a string, but it (obviously) isn't - so I guess I have more digging to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes by later - I managed to solve this issue by moving up one level in my DB reference (going from `Listings/$listing/ListingData/BasicInfo` to `Listings/$listing/ListingData/`) it seems Firebase was smart enough to grab the specific information I needed on its own (instead of needing me to specifically tell it where it is), everything works fine now!